# How can my EF migrations work with the appsettings.json in the main project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, appsettings

Currently I have one appsettings.json file in the main project and use it in all projects whenever I need some of the configurations defined in it, but for my Persistence project I have another appsettings.json file that contain only db string, but I need it only when I ran EF migrations, db updates,... because otherwise it doesn't work.

If I remove that second file, project works, but if I try to run EF db update I get this error:

> The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not
> optional. The expected physical path was
> 'Project\Persistence\bin\Debug\net6.0\appsettings.json'.

How can I achieve running migrations while having only one appsettings.json in the main project?

Comment: You need to run the `dotnet ef` tool in the root project, the one that actually has an `appsettings.json` file

Comment: are you attempting to run migrations through code? If so, why not generate a script and migrate the database independently?

Comment: @AsPas I am running through console

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, but all the packages related to EF are part of my Persistence project, so I didn't want to add them there because I don't use them. Even if I try to add reference to  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, because I got error for it, after that I got this: No DbContext was found in assembly 'WebAPI'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue whenever i tried to encapsulate my persistence layer into a separate project, because it was used by many other projects. There is no comfortable way of achieving this as far i know. I stuck with having separate configuration files even though this wasn't ideal.

However, an option based anti-solution is to reflect onto the fact, that encapsulating the persistence layer into a separate project might not be useful, as it introduces framework dependent issues like this. It only provides a meaningful advantage, if more than one project depend on it, because that way the persistence layer code is shared between several projects.